# Read PDF file in JavaScript and send the data through an API

Tags: javascript, python, api

I'm basically looking for functionality equivalent to this Python code in JS:

It read a pdf file and send the bytes through  a Post request

```
from requests import get, post
source = "my_pdf.pdf"

with open(source, "rb") as f:
    data_bytes = f.read()

post_url = "my_url"
resp = post(url = post_url, data = data_bytes)
```

At the moment I'm using the react-jsonschema-form library, which has and option to read/load files form the following code:

```
{
  "title": "Files",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "file": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "data-url",
      "title": "Single file"
    }

  }
}
```

The above json schema generates this form:

[image]

With that I can load a file form my computer:

[image]

But from here, I don't know how to send the data to an API

Comment: What have you problems with? Reading a file or sending a post request?

Comment: @IgorDragushhak I just edited the question